# 12703. 00000 - "this character set conversion is not supported"

Tags: oracle, plsql, stored-functions

i'm using a function to convert currencies but i'm getting this error 12703. 00000 -  "this character set conversion is not supported", i don't know why.

**here's the code i'm using**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION convert(r_comm IN commande.ref_commande%type,
                   devise IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN commande.montant_ttc%type IS
mt commande.montant_ttc%type;
montant NUMBER(20) :=0;
BEGIN
    IF devise = 'dollar' THEN
        SELECT montant_ttc INTO mt FROM commande WHERE ref_commande = r_comm;
        montant := mt*10;
    END IF;
    IF devise = 'euro' THEN
        SELECT montant_ttc INTO mt FROM commande WHERE ref_commande = r_comm;
        montant := mt*11;
    END IF;
RETURN montant;
END convert;
/

DECLARE
r_comm commande.ref_commande%type :=1;
devise VARCHAR2(6) := 'dollar';
mt NUMBER(20);
BEGIN
mt := convert(r_comm, devise);
dbms_output.put_line(mt);
END;
/
```

**THE ERROR**
[image]
**THE TABLE**

[image]

Comment: How would anyone know by looking at this code?  What line is the error on?  What is the data in the tables?

Comment: @OldProgrammer i updated the question, maybe you can spot the problem now

Comment: @OldProgrammer ligne 6 refers to the function call, the function was compiled successfully

Comment: @OldProgrammer the question has been answered, maybe you'll want to know what the problem was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the call is going to the different `convert` function (oracle provides [convert](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620) function).

> The Oracle `CONVERT()` function converts a string from one character
>   set to another.

**Solution:**

I would suggest changing the name of your `function` as the `convert` is the oracle function.

Or

Use your `schemaname.function` while calling it. But It is not recommended to have same object name so option 1 is better.

Cheers!!